# Direct conversion of html page into PDf

Tags: php, html, pdf

I am converting html form into pdf soon after after entering values. Its working fine. But when I want to directly convert html form to pdf with some calculation then its generating error. for example : i want to divide age by 2 when it printing pdf file.  Here is my html and php code :

```
<div id="html_div">
 <form action="generate_pdf.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Enter Age">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit_val" value="GENERATE PDF">
 </form>
</div>
```

and this is my php code

```
<?php
namespace Dompdf;
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit_val']))
{
$dompdf = new Dompdf(); 
$dompdf->loadHtml('
<table border=1 align=center width=400>
<tr><td>Age : </td><td>'.$_POST['age'].'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Half Age : </td><td>'.$_POST['age'].'/2 </td></tr>

</table>
');
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("",array("Attachment" => false));
exit(0);
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the error message, and what line does it occur on?

Comment: You understand that you're not actually doing a calculation here, you're just adding the literal string `/2` onto the end of the age, because it's inside the quotes for the table cell and row closing tags? How would you do the calculation if you were just using `echo`?

Comment: yes you are right, how can i calculate ???? inside table .

Comment: @droopsnoot instead of giving =40/2 which is 20, its just showing 40/2

Comment: Well, it will, do, because you're just adding `/2` as a string literal. As I asked before, how would you do this in `echo`? Once you have that working, you'll see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_val']))
{
    $dompdf = new Dompdf(); 
    $answer = $_POST['age']/2;
    $dompdf->loadHtml('
    <table border=1 align=center width=400>
    <tr><td>Age : </td><td>'.$_POST['age'].'</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Half Age : </td><td>'.$answer.' </td></tr>
    </table>');
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("",array("Attachment" => false));
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You'll get a more favourable response to your post if you take the time to explain your answer, including what you've done and why you expect that it solves the problem. Just dumping code is actually not very helpful most of the time. See also [answer]. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. You can [edit] your answer anytime you like :-)